# How to initialize a Class-instance and print it's public variable?

Tags: class, oop, algorithmic-trading, mql4, metatrader4

I've got the following code:

```
/*  1 */    class Market {
/*  2 */    public:
/*  3 */    
/*  4 */        double foo;
/*  5 */    
/*  6 */        /* 
/*  7 */         * Constructor:
/*  8 */         */
/*  9 */        Market() {
/* 10 */            foo = 2;
/* 11 */        }
/* 12 */    };
/* 13 */    
/* 14 */    Market market;              // GLOBALLY VISIBLE VAR
/* 15 */    
/* 16 */    void OnInit() {             // OnInit event-process
/* 17 */      market = new Market();    // <------------------- 17,10
/* 18 */      Print(market.foo);
/* 19 */    }
/* 20 */    
/* 21 */    void OtherFunc() {
/* 22 */      Print(market.foo);
/* 23 */    }
```

However when I'm trying to compile, I've got the following error:

> test.mq4(17,10) : **`error 280:`** '=' - object required

Basically I'm planing to create an object instance and receive a pointer to it, so I can use it globally across the code.

I've checked the [**`MQL4`** docs page](https://docs.mql4.com/basis/types/classes) about classes, but it didn't help me.

I've also tried to assign the class as:

```
Market *market = new Market();
```

and then I declared that variable in the first line as:

```
Market market;
```

but then I've got this warning:

> test.mq4(17,11) : **`warning 62:`** declaration of 'market' hides global declaration at line 14

and the file compiles, but I don't want to hide the global declaration (since it won't be available in the other functions), **I want to assign an object instance into the global declaration**, so I can print the object's variable across the whole code.

**How do I do that?**

Comment: @user3666197 This is the complete simplified independent code, the lines are corresponding to the same code from the errors if you copy & paste. Re 'hides global' warning, I've added additional clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### So, let's start the "inventory of don't-s" in Advanced-`MQL4`

First advice, **never** rely on web-sources, **always** check the auto-updated `IDE`-**`Help`**. Even this does not contain a 100% correct text / code-samples, but it is by far closer to the actual compiler-grammar, than the obsoleting web texts.

Next advice, **always** remember **`MQL4` is not a `C` language** - strange differences may kill otherwise smart idea.

---

### Syntax FIRST:

> **Object Create Operator `new`**
>   The `new` operator automatically creates an object of a corresponding size, calls the object constructor and returns a **`descriptor`** of created object. In case of failure, the operator returns a **`null descriptor`** that can be compared with the **`NULL`** constant.
>   The **`new`** operator can be applied only to `class` objects. It can't be applied to structures.

---

> **Object Pointers**
>   In `MQL4`, there is a possibility to dynamically create objects of complex type. This is done by the **`new`** operator, which returns a **`descriptor`** of the created object. `Descriptor` is 8 bytes large. Syntactically, object descriptors in `MQL4` are **similar** to pointers in `C++`.
>   **Examples:**
>   `MyObject* hobject= new MyObject();`
>   **In contrast to `C++`**, the `hobject` variable from example above is **not a pointer to memory**, but **rather an object `descriptor`**. Furthermore, in `MQL5` all objects in function parameters **must** be passed by reference.

---

### Retaining a value visible on global scope NEXT:

Using the above, **`hobject`** ought be visible on a global-scope, supposing it's declaration was in due place, before any system-event-handler / user defined code started ( and sure, on condition there is no name-masking taking  place inside any lower-level scope-range of the code ).

### Epilogue:

After an exposure to a bit more than a few `hundreds man*years` of **`MQL4`** hands-on experience, all advanced solutions started to get designed as a distributed framework, rather than have to remain as victims of language-irregularities and syntax-creeps. One may consider this as a bit safer alternative than to invest some remarkable amount of software engineering into ecosystem, that changes faster, than an economy / performance of a repetitive code-base re-engineering might manage to keep the pace of the moving sands.

> <kbd>**Anyway :**</kbd> **Welcome** to the **Wild Worlds of `MQL4`**

Comment: No, it shall work. Kindly follow and adapt the example in IDE-Help-MQL4 Reference / Language Basics / Data Types / Object Pointers

Answer (score 0):

The declaration of global variable should looks like:

```
Market *market;
```

then to initialize the class (e.g. in `OnInit()`) you should do like:

```
market = new Market();
```

Then print the class variables (e.g. `market.foo`) or call methods as usual (e.g. `market.Foo()`).

Answer (score 0):

### Let's elaborate the case per-partes:

---

**The more important part of the story:**

The **`class`** syntax provides means for a **very important concept** of an **O**bject-**O**riented-**D**esign **mode-of-thinking**. The Object-boundary here, serves as a cardinal protection barrier, not as just a next syntax-sugar toy ( while some languages do enforce this principal access-barrier protection, saving the internal worlds of the Objects with an absolute isolation from any attempts to externally try to "directly" interact with class instance-variables ( such as **`SmallTalk`** does this, on an excellent level ) some other languages, that started their first visits into OOP-territories some remarkable decades later, do not exhibit such clarity in mental concepts and may allow "hybrid"-accessess ( which may and do confuse a lot about colliding programming practices, that sort of bypass the original **principal** OOD-architecture benefits -- all that at full risk being on the programming / testing teams side ).

```
   // DEMO                GetFoo:
      public: double DEMO_GetFoo(){ return( aClassVARIABLE_foo );
                                    }
```

or even a directly printing `<class-method>`

```
   // DEMO         PrintActualFooVALUE:
      public: void PrintActualFooVALUE(){ PrintFormat( "Value of foo == %23.10f",
                                                       aClassVARIABLE_foo
                                                       );
                                          }
```

are much more OOD-ed, protecting the `private: double aClassVARIABLE_foo;` from external worlds, than a universally granted public permit to spoil the precious object-toys via a naked ( freely exposed ) `public: double foo;`.

> <kbd>**`BEST PRACTICE: KEEP THE BENEFITS OF THE CORE MOTIVATION FOR OOD`**</kbd>
> If one may do so,
> rather prefer to avoid such dangers and fine tune one's own OOD craftsmanship.
> **Why?** For a sake of an academic OOD-purity?
> **No.**
> The first need to change an unimportant implementation detail inside a **`class`** will teach one, why the very due separation of the inner-world of the object and the outer-world of the extra-object reality is important.
> The access via `<class-methods>` completely prevents and principally avoids any code-base impacts outside of the modified `class` right because the access `<class-methods>` reflect & mediate all internal changes accordingly, without the external worlds were ever in a need to know details about the **real internal class-representation** of (an assumed only `double` ) **`foo`** or whatever more complex stuff one needs to handle.

### Using
the access by class-methods,
rather than assignments to a naked `public: <class-variable>`,
the code
may look like this:

```
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//|              ___StackOverflow_OOP_class_public_variable_DEMO.mq4 |
//|                                       Copyright © 1987-2016 [MS] |
//|                                                       nowhere.no |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+ >>> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37368437/how-to-initialize-a-class-instance-and-print-its-public-variable
#property copyright "Copyright © 1987-2016 [MS]"
#property link      "nowhere.no"
#property version   "1.00"
#property strict

class DEMO_Class_Market {
   // public:
      private:
                  double   aClassVARIABLE_foo;
   // DEMO GetFoo:
      public:     double   DEMO_GetFoo(){       
                              return( aClassVARIABLE_foo );
                           }
   // DEMO ChgFoo:
      public:     double   DEMO_ChgFoo( double aNewVALUE_to_SET  = EMPTY_VALUE ){
                              double aTempRetVALUE = aClassVARIABLE_foo;
                                                     aClassVARIABLE_foo   = aNewVALUE_to_SET;
                              return( aTempRetVALUE );
                              }
   // DEMO_<Constructor>:
      DEMO_Class_Market(){
                           PrintFormat( "DEMO_Class_Market::<Constructor> has initially seen a variable foo == %23.10f", aClassVARIABLE_foo );
                           aClassVARIABLE_foo = 2.;
                           PrintFormat( "DEMO_Class_Market::<Constructor> has set a new value into var. foo == %23.10f", aClassVARIABLE_foo );
                           }
   // DEMO_<Destructor>:
     ~DEMO_Class_Market(){  
                           PrintFormat( "DEMO_Class_Market::<Destructor>  has seen a current value of a foo == %23.10f", aClassVARIABLE_foo );
                           }
      };

//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Script program start function                                    |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
void  OnStart(){

      DEMO_Class_Market anInstanceOfMARKET;

      double            anExternalQueryForClassVariableVALUE = EMPTY;

      int               aReturnCODE = GetClassInstancePublicVariableVALUE( anInstanceOfMARKET, anExternalQueryForClassVariableVALUE );
      PrintFormat(      "1.st call to GetClassInstancePublicVariableVALUE( anInstanceOfMARKET, ... ) function. The actual call returned [aReturnCODE == %d ], the anExternalQueryForClassVariableVALUE is == %23.10f", aReturnCODE, anExternalQueryForClassVariableVALUE );

                        aReturnCODE = ChgClassInstancePublicVariableVALUE( anInstanceOfMARKET, 6666.6666, anExternalQueryForClassVariableVALUE );
      PrintFormat(      "1.st call to ChgClassInstancePublicVariableVALUE( anInstanceOfMARKET, 6666.6666 ) function. The actual call returned [aReturnCODE == %d ], the returned previous value of a class-[private] variable was == %23.10f", aReturnCODE, anExternalQueryForClassVariableVALUE );

                        aReturnCODE = GetClassInstancePublicVariableVALUE( anInstanceOfMARKET, anExternalQueryForClassVariableVALUE );
      PrintFormat(      "2.st call to GetClassInstancePublicVariableVALUE( anInstanceOfMARKET, ... ) function. The actual call returned [aReturnCODE == %d ], the anExternalQueryForClassVariableVALUE is == %23.10f", aReturnCODE, anExternalQueryForClassVariableVALUE );
   }
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
#define RET_OK    0
#define RET_ERROR EMPTY
#define VAL_ERROR EMPTY_VALUE
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
int   GetClassInstancePublicVariableVALUE( DEMO_Class_Market       &aClassINSTANCE, //   |-> DEMO_Class_Market INSTANCE = <aClassINSTANCE> of a type DEMO_Class_Market
                                           double                  &aDoubleVALUE    // <=|   returns RESULT = ???.???
                                           ){
      aDoubleVALUE = aClassINSTANCE.DEMO_GetFoo();                                  // STOR <class-method> RET VALUE IN RESULT
      return( RET_OK );                                                             // FLAG RET_OK in JIT/RET
   }
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
int   ChgClassInstancePublicVariableVALUE( DEMO_Class_Market       &aClassINSTANCE,       //   |-> DEMO_Class_Market INSTANCE = <aClassINSTANCE> of a type DEMO_Class_Market
                                           double const             aNewDoubleVALUEtoSET, //   |-> a value to SET
                                           double                  &aReplacedVALUE        // <=|   returns an OLD value
                                           ){
      aReplacedVALUE = aClassINSTANCE.DEMO_ChgFoo( aNewDoubleVALUEtoSET );                // CHNG NEW VALUE IN VARIABLE via <class-method>, RET OLD VALUE
      return( RET_OK );                                                                   // FLAG RET_OK in JIT/RET
   }
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

The results from [ **MT4 Terminal** ] reordered as per flow of time

```
2016.11.03 14:35:37.655 Script ___StackOverflow_OOP_class_public_variable_DEMO XAUUSD,H1: loaded successfully
2016.11.03 14:35:37.655 ___StackOverflow_OOP_class_public_variable_DEMO XAUUSD,H1: initialized
2016.11.03 14:35:37.655 ___StackOverflow_OOP_class_public_variable_DEMO XAUUSD,H1: DEMO_Class_Market::<Constructor> has initially seen a variable foo ==            0.0000000000
2016.11.03 14:35:37.655 ___StackOverflow_OOP_class_public_variable_DEMO XAUUSD,H1: DEMO_Class_Market::<Constructor> has set a new value into var. foo ==            2.0000000000

2016.11.03 14:35:37.655 ___StackOverflow_OOP_class_public_variable_DEMO XAUUSD,H1: 1.st call to GetClassInstancePublicVariableVALUE( anInstanceOfMARKET, ... ) function. The actual call returned [aReturnCODE == 0 ], the anExternalQueryForClassVariableVALUE is ==            2.0000000000

2016.11.03 14:35:37.655 ___StackOverflow_OOP_class_public_variable_DEMO XAUUSD,H1: 1.st call to ChgClassInstancePublicVariableVALUE( anInstanceOfMARKET, 6666.6666 ) function. The actual call returned [aReturnCODE == 0 ], the returned previous value of a class-[private] variable was ==            2.0000000000

2016.11.03 14:35:37.655 ___StackOverflow_OOP_class_public_variable_DEMO XAUUSD,H1: 2.st call to GetClassInstancePublicVariableVALUE( anInstanceOfMARKET, ... ) function. The actual call returned [aReturnCODE == 0 ], the anExternalQueryForClassVariableVALUE is ==         6666.6666000000

2016.11.03 14:35:37.655 ___StackOverflow_OOP_class_public_variable_DEMO XAUUSD,H1: DEMO_Class_Market::<Destructor>  has seen a current value of a foo ==         6666.6666000000
2016.11.03 14:35:37.655 ___StackOverflow_OOP_class_public_variable_DEMO XAUUSD,H1: uninit reason 0
2016.11.03 14:35:37.655 Script ___StackOverflow_OOP_class_public_variable_DEMO XAUUSD,H1: removed
```

---

### The declaration  <sup>whether on global / local scope</sup>  does not require any other modification in syntax:

one may just test both declaration alternatives, via mutually-exclusive (un)commented the former and the latter declaration instances.

```
.
..
...
DEMO_Class_Market anInstanceOfMARKET;  // DECLARE'd on a global scope

//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Script program start function                                    |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
void  OnStart(){

   // DEMO_Class_Market anInstanceOfMARKET;  // DECLARE'd on a local scope
...
..
.
```

---

### The less important part of the story:
 <sub>*(cit.)* "practical code example how to assign/attach an object instance to the global variable."</sub>

> It has been shown in the above posted **`MQL4`** code in practice,
>  as was requested in the bounty reasoning paragraph,
> that a class-instance can be freely attached to an **`MQL4`** variable existing on either a global scope or a local scope.
> In case, one needs some context-specific initialisations to be executed upon a code-execution visit to an **`OnInit()`** event-handler,
> one may rather design an additional <sup>( almost-pythonic :o) )</sup> `<class-method>`
> **`public: void __init__( ... ){ ... }`**
> to receive additional levels of control
> for such context-specific / MT4-state-aware `<class-instance>` initialisation customisations during `OnInit()` and request there a call to `anInstanceOfMARKET.__init__( ... );` once the [ MetaTrader Terminal 4 ] graph details have become known and it's parameters and other digital content have become accessible from the live-execution of the **`MQL4`**-code ( which is not guarranteed in the moment, where a class-instantiation process happens right at the code of the declaration in the place feasible for a definition on a global scope ).